# Duplicate document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, inheritance

I am very new to sharepoint and need a little help

I have created a communications site, I have then created new pages within the site and inserted a document structure.  I then began to populate the document structure with folders only to find that the same folder structure had appeared on the other pages and what ever I do to one it happens on all, how do i break the inheritance please?  I need all pages to be different

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Have you added same document library on all pages? You can try creating different library views (by applying filters as per your requirements) & then those views to different pages.

Comment: Ok, ill give that a go, how do I do that as Im still learning Sharepoint, a bit of a 'how to' guide - thanks again

Comment: Check this [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9) for creating/editing list/library views.

Comment: Hi, Ive made different views for each page and applied it when on that page but its still copying the same view to each page, thusly im still seeing the same folder tree on each.  If I go right back to where i created the pages, how do insert a document section into each without it copying to all others??? Thanks again